# \Magento\Framework\Registry already exists in context object on compile

Tags: magento2, error, blocks, class

when I do compile I do get the following error which is referencing my custom module Blocks, class

```
        Incorrect dependency in class ...
\Magento\Framework\Registry already exists in context object
```

my constructor looks like

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    );
}
```

what went wrong in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says that `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context` already has `\Magento\Framework\Registry` in it. So instead of injecting both of them, you should inject only Context and get registry from it via `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context::getRegistry()`

Answer (score 6):

Just upload your code same as below,

Keep `$this->_coreRegistry = $context->getRegistry();`

Full code,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    $this->_productsFactory = $productsFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $context->getRegistry();
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    );
}
```

Remove var folder and compile again.
Registry is already called inside product block so its display compile errror in your case.

Comment: When I use above method for resultFactory then getting error  (RuntimeException): Source class "\Nitesh\ModuleName\Controller\Payment\Result" for "Nitesh\ModuleName\Controller\Payment\ResultFactory" generation does not exist.

Comment: You have to remove var folder from root and check

Comment: tried after removing var directory but still error comes